# I Still don't get HMAC or how Signing a request works

Tags: asp.net, security, hmac

I work on ASP.NET and was just reading this from the amazon directory http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html where it states

> Informally, we call this process "signing the request," and we call
>   the output of the HMAC algorithm the "signature" because it simulates
>   the security properties of a real signature. Finally, you add this
>   signature as a parameter of the request, using the syntax described in
>   this section.
>
> When the system receives an authenticated request, it fetches the AWS
>   Secret Access Key that you claim to have, and uses it in the same way
>   to compute a "signature" for the message it received. It then compares
>   the signature it calculated against the signature presented by the
>   requester.

But i presume both the requests wont be same right. Request is signed (great!!) but HMAC of the response from the client browser is going to be different since it contains extra data Right? so how come requests can validate even though they are valid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read the whole of the paragraphs you quoted from. Right before the piece you quoted it says:

> To authenticate a request, you first concatenate selected elements of the request to form a string. You then use your AWS Secret Access Key to calculate the HMAC of that string.

So you calculate your HMAC from those selected elements, and when you submit the request, the server calculates an HMAC from those same elements, and then they are compared.

Comment: I assume so but I'm afraid I don't know for sure. I know a little bit about secret key auth but not much about ASP.NET. :)